# Apache2 Option index on centos 6.3

Tags: indexing, centos, apache2, virtualhost

On a newly installed Centos 6.3

I imported the config from Ubuntu for a virtualhost. Here is the piece of config

```
DocumentRoot /otherhome/test.cofares.net
ServerName test.cofares.net

<Directory "/otherhome/test.cofares.net">
  allow from all
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

A request to the http://test.cofares.net  I get the folowwing error in the error log

```
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /otherhome/test.cofares.net/
```

The directory index worked for a sub directory http://test.cofares.net/test is OK

Any suggestions what is missing?

The same config work well with Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And make sure to restart apache after applying:

```
<Directory "/otherhome/test.cofares.net">
  Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order Allow, Deny
  Allow from All
  Satisfy All
</Directory>
```

And perhaps try this with `Satisfy Any` instead:

```
<Directory "/otherhome/test.cofares.net">
  Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order Allow, Deny
  Allow from All
  Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

**EDIT:** Those didn’t seem to work? Then try this. Note I am setting up the whole `<VirtualHost>` directive & removed quotes from the `<Directory>` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /otherhome/test.cofares.net
   ServerName test.cofares.net

   <Directory /otherhome/test.cofares.net>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     Allow from All
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: after digging i found the offending conf in welcome.conf I removed it it is now OK thanks for your helps <LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little I noticed that thire is a global rule (in conf.d/welcome.conf)  that prevent indexing the / directory of any virtual server

By removing it it is now ok

Here is the rule that must be change

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
  Options -Indexes
  ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```